# Struct array string merge with another string in c

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, c-strings, string-literals

So i have a problem where the string in struct merge with another array. See the code and output for more explanation.
Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct print
{
    char code[3];
    char name[10];
}test[2]={"001","Alen","101","Paul"};

int main()
{

    int x;
    for(x=0;x<2;x++)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n",test[x].code,test[x].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
001Alen Alen
101Paul Paul

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.017 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The output is wrong, it should be like this:

```
001 Alen
101 Paul
```

So why the "name" merge in "code" variables? It shouldn't be like that. So how do i solve this? Thank you.

Comment: @kalum's answer is correct, alternatively, use `char *` in your struct.

Comment: Using `char *` works nicely in this case, but will have interesting side-effects with respect to memory allocation if the struct is used otherwise than it is in the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C strings need to be NUL terminated. Your `code` array field is one character too small. Change `char code[3];` to be `char code[4];`

Answer (score 1):

You declared a character array within the structure with exactly `3` characters

```
char code[3];
```

Strings literals like this `"001"` have `4` characters. The last character of such string literals is the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

So in this declaration

```
struct print
{
    char code[3];
    char name[10];
}test[2]={"001","Alen","101","Paul"};
```

the character array `code` is initialized by three characters of corresponding string literals. The last character, the terminating zero character `'\0'`, of the string literals is not stored in the array.

Thus the character array `code`  does not contain a string.

To output it using the conversion specifier `s` you should write

```
printf("%.3s %s\n",test[x].code,test[x].name);
```

Another approach is to enlarge the array as for example

```
char code[4];
```

In this case it can store the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string literals and you may write

```
printf("%s %s\n",test[x].code,test[x].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To perhaps put this in more visual terms, judging from the output you're receiving your program is laying out a `struct print` in memory like so:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------+
| code      | name                                  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you initialize with `{"001", "Alen"}`, this looks like:

```
+-----------+---------------------------------------+
| code      | name                                  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | A | l | e | n | \0|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Because the `code` field only provides three characters, there isn't room for the null terminator. Thus if we point at the beginning of `code` and print that as a *string*, the program will print until it hits a null terminator.

We can see this demonstrated by a simple program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct print
{
    char code[3];
    char name[10];
};

int main() {
    struct print x = {"001", "Alen"};

    for (char *ch = x.code; *ch != '\0'; ch++) {
        printf("> %c\n", *ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When we run this:

```
> 0
> 0
> 1
> A
> l
> e
> n
```

But if we initialize `code` with a two digit code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct print
{
    char code[3];
    char name[10];
};

int main() {
    struct print x = {"01", "Alen"};

    for (char *ch = x.code; *ch != '\0'; ch++) {
        printf("> %c\n", *ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which when run:

```
> 0
> 1
```

As stated previously, the most obvious solution is to increase the size of the `code` field to leave room for the null terminator.